# How can we compare two program dependence graph?

Tags: linux, image-processing, graph, ocaml, frama-c

This is one example program dependence graph.**

[image: Dependency graph]

This is the code which generate above graph. I want to compare two graph of these types , is there any method two compare these graph for percentage of similarity.I am also thinking for comparing image of graph to get the simiarity percentage , please suggest how can i do it.

```
digraph cfg {
subgraph cluster_sum {
graph [label="sum"];
s1[label="i = 0;"];
s1 -> s2;
s2[label="sum_0 = 0;"];
s2 -> s3;
s3[label="i = x;"];
s3 -> s4;
s4[label="<loop>"];
s4 -> s6;
s6[label="if i <= y"];
s6 -> s8;
s6 -> s7;
s7[label="<break>"];
s7 -> s11;
s8[label="<enter block>"];
s8 -> s9;
s9[label="sum_0 -= i;"];
s9 -> s10;
s10[label="i ++;"];
s10 -> s4;
s11[label="<return>"];
}
subgraph cluster_main {
  graph [label="main"];
  s13[label="res = 0;"];
  s13 -> s14;
  s14[label="a = 2;"];
  s14 -> s15;
  s15[label="b = 5;"];
  s15 -> s16;
  s16[label="res = sum(a,b);"];
  s16 -> s17;
  s17[label="printf(\"%d\",res);"];
  s17 -> s18;
  s18[label="__retres = 0;"];
  s18 -> s21;
  s21[label="<return>"];
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

well, in general it is an open and unsolvable? question. You can evaluate both programs using abstract interpretation and compare the results. But I don't think that you're expecting this answer.

The easiest approach would be to transform the graph (that can be read in OCaml using `ocamlgraph` library) to a normalized form, where all syntactic differences are removed (for example, all variables are renamed using common naming scheme or substituted with regular expressions), and then you can compare the resulting graphs, based on your compare function.

But this is just a hack, of course. For more sophisticated you should take several courses in program analysis, write a thesis, and answer to itself, that in general it is unsolvable... But eventually, you will write something like [BinDiff](http://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html).

What concerning comparison two images, then I think it is even a more crude hack. But a usual approach it to make a 2D convolution, that will return you the measure of equality. OCaml `fftw` library has everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

The approach comparing graphs by looking their rendered images is bad: Graphviz replaces the position of nodes freely and largely even with slight modification of graphs.

You should compare graphs in a more algebraic way, but the algorithm would be highly dependent on how you define the "similarity". If I were you, I try the edit distance of trees. I recently used it to measure the "similarity" of OCaml type expressions (yes, their ASTs are basically trees but can have loops) and got a nice result. You should be able to find lots of information by searching "edit distance of tree".

Program execution flows have loops therefore probably they should be compared as general directed graphs rather than trees with little number of loops. I believe there should be some research works specialized for it, but I am not knowledgeable at all.

For implementation, I have never tried, but OCamlDot (http://zoggy.github.io/ocamldot/) could be used to parse the dot file format to obtain the algebraic representation of graphs.